sed loop not working on Mac OS as it would work on Linux
I am trying to use the following sed loop (to remove newline char) on mac (bash) but it does not seem to be working. Previously had been using it on Linux and it worked:
cat temp | sed ':start;N;s/\n//g;t start'

Please advise if I am doing something wrong here or need to set sed specifically for mac (bash).
Thanks,
Abid Ghufran
Tried a few sed switches including -E but that also did not work.

UUoC.

By its nature, sed is line oriented and the non GNU version cannot easily be used to remove line endings.
You can burlesque it with this cross platform sed script:
sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n//g' file

But once you start getting there with sed you might want to think about other methods.
tr is a better tool for this:
echo 'Line 1
Line 2
Line 3' | tr '\n' '!'

Prints:
Line 1!Line 2!Line 3!

To remove all \n, you would do:
tr -d '\n' < file

You could also use awk:
awk '{printf $0}' file

The advantage of tr or awk is they work regardless of the platform -- no head scratching!

Use the hold space to stack your data, then switch it back to the pattern space to edit and print at the end.
sed -n 'H; ${x; s/\n//g; p; }' temp

